# How do I fix a SubView to the bottom of screen for iPhone 4 & 5 in XCode without using AutoLayout?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a subview to display a mobile ad in my XCode Project. The ad loads perfectly fine and works with iPhone 5 but not with iPhone 4.

I am trying to get the ad to fix to the bottom of the screen on both iPhone 4 & 5 but it doesn't want to do it for iPhone 4.

I am not using Auto Layout and do not wish to - is there a way I can do this programatically or using interface builder?

Really stuck, seems simple but please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the frame of your ad view (let name it adView) is already set, you can do like this :

```
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-adView.frame.size.width, 
                            [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-adView.frame.size.height, 
                            adView.frame.size.width, 
                            adView.frame.size.height
)];
```

**EDIT**

In case of application display a status bar , it should look like :

```
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-adView.frame.size.width, 
                            [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-adView.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, 
                            adView.frame.size.width, 
                            adView.frame.size.height
)];
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that except I can see the top half of the banner now and the bottom half falls out of the screen view...Do I have to make some adjustments?

Comment: Yes, it might be because of the status bar if you display one. So ad `-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height` to the first parameter of CGRectMake

Comment: Could you please show me how it should look in context of the whole code as I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: I do have one issue though now. I am using UIWebView in some ViewControllers with a toolbar at the bottom but that is now covered by the banner? 

How do I ensure the banner doesnt cover the toolbar?

Comment: The question is to know what view contains which one. To be sure, maybe you can have a global view which contain a content view and the ad. This content view will be the actual view containing the severals uiwebview.